# When to set values for UIViewController's custom properties when using UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController?

Tags: swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

1. When initiating an UIViewController from code the data that it needs to run is passed as arguments in the init method and saved in non optional properties, **so when `ViewDidLoad()` is called you can do whatever you need with the data and the view.**
2. When performing a segue, the properties are declared as implicit unwrapped optionals (because storyboard needs the init methods without extra parameters in order to init it). After initialization `loadView()` is called and outlets are set. Finally, `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called, where data is passed and set in the properties previously declared, **so when `ViewDidLoad()` is called you can do whatever you need with the data and the view.**
3. How to pass data when using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`? As I understand, storyboard automatically calls `loadView()` and **ends with `viewDidLoad()` without giving you the opportunity to pass data to the custom properties you declared, so at that point data is not ready to use.**

(It is clear that I can set the properties just after calling `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`, but I think that this procedure does not warranty to set them before `viewDidLoad()`is called)

For example, this (most probably) will work:

1. Call to `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`
2. Set values of custom properties inside the destination UIViewController
3. `viewDidLoad()` is called, and inside I can use the data and the view objects.(because I gave value to those properties **before**)

But imagine if:

1. Call to `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`
   ...
   ... I take some time to give value to custom properties ...
   ...
2. `viewDidLoad()` is called, and inside I use the custom properties. The app most likely will crash because the values of those properties are not set.
3. Set values of custom properties inside the destination UIViewController (here `viewDidLoad()` is already executed)

Comment: Another point on the list "why storyboards are technical depth". ;) You can set the properties after you have instantiated from the storyboard and use them in `viewWillAppear`. I'm not sure about what `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController` does and if it calls `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Id you need to set properties in destinationvc before viewdidload try awakefromnib

Answer (score 0):

> viewDidLoad() is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was
>   loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView
>   method.............You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

It is true that `viewDidLoad()` is for additional initialization on views, as when you initialize a view controller (either with -init or -initWithNibName:bundle:), it doesn't actually create and initialize the view. When you call -view for the first time, it calls -loadView (I guess that's why `viewDidLoad()` is necessary, for **additional** initialization ). However, UIViewController is a Class itself, I don't think there is anything wrong to set the properties of a class Object.

I also had a look at the definition of `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`:

> You use this method to create view controller objects that you want to
>   manipulate and present programmatically in your application. Before
>   you can use this method to retrieve a view controller, you must
>   explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier string in Interface
>   Builder.
>
> This method creates a **new instance** of the specified view controller
>   each time you call it.

I emphasize the `new instance` because it's different from creating a new viewController. By using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`, all the views you create in your storyboard will be automatically instantiated for you, and all the outlets and actions will be set up as you specified in the storyboard.

As the Apple Doc says "manipulate and present programmatically in your application", I think you can feel free to do so.

Comment: Okey, you are right. The `loadView()` method is called when accessing the view property, **except** when using the UIViewController from the storyboard (for example when using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`): in this case it is called automatically. So the problem is that after using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController` I can not see a place to give value to those custom properties that warranties that they have their value **before** ´viewDidLoad()´is called. (correct me if I am wrong, I think it is this way)

Comment: (Imagine that after using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController` I spend a lot of time giving value to the custom properties: ´viewDidLoad()´ could be called in between, so if I use those properties inside ´viewDidLoad()´ to configure the view, the app most probably will crash because they would not have value)

Comment: Ok, I admit the app could crash when you spend a lot of time giving value. But that's another problem then(and a solution is available ). Actually, you are unlikely to spend a lot of time giving value unless you are doing some tasks like downloading data from Internet, in situation  like this, you should put these tasks into your destination viewController and then set properties in your destination viewController. However, explanation here doesn't make much sense until you apply it to practice and start to tackle the specific problem.